# using BCL for file compression

Tags: c++, compression

4.5 Huffman_Compress

```
Syntax:

outsize = Huffman_Compress(in,out,insize)

outsize Size of output buffer after compression
in Pointer to the input buffer (uncompressed data)
out Pointer to the output buffer (compressed data)
insize Size of input buffer
The output buffer must be able to hold insize * 101 / 100 + 320 bytes.
```

4.6 Huffman_Uncompress
Syntax:

Huffman_Uncompress(in,out,insize,outsize)

```
in Pointer to the input buffer (compressed data)
out Pointer to the output buffer (uncompressed data)
insize Size of input buffer
outsize Size of output buffer
The output buffer must be able to hold outsize bytes
```

What size of output buffer should be used? I tried to find some examples but found nothing

Comment: I don't know what you're compressing, but I would venture to say that you won't get much gain out of just Huffman coding. You should look for other libraries such as lz4, zlib, zstd, and lzma2.

Comment: Thanks i tried to use zlib but it is too much complicated. I was looking for something simple as it only can be I also implemented Huffman alg by myself but it works only with text files.

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than zlib's `compress()` and `uncompress()` functions.

Comment: Yes, I should read more information before I asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some more information on `Huffman_Compress`, it would be possible to determine a maximum compression ratio and an overhead. With that you could calculate the maximum possible expansion due to decompression, and allocate an output buffer accordingly. However you're not going to like the answer for large compressed inputs.

Since it appears that the decompression needs to be completed in a single call, you should send the uncompressed length with the compressed data. Simply prepend the compressed data with, say, eight bytes containing the uncompressed length. On the other end, read the eight byte length, allocate a buffer of that size, and decompress the remainder into that buffer.

Comment: Thank you. It's looks like it is standard method to know size of uncompressed file, am I right? I thought it is something wrong with my library but after I tried to understand how to work with zlib i was faced with the same problem :)

Comment: What is more common is to not decompress in one fell swoop, but rather to decompress the data in chunks. The same is true for compression, which is what the inflate and deflate families of functions are for. Compression formats are generally streaming formats, so that you are never required to have the whole thing in memory at once. You can read in pieces and process or write out pieces until done. Then there is no limit on the size of data that you can process, other than time. The memory required is fixed.

Comment: At least it is working. I have added size of input(original) file to compressed file. When I call uncompress function (Huffman_Uncompress(in,out,insize,outsize)) I have already size to put in outsize variable

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your library only handles in-memory data, based on what you've posted. It *may* be able to do file-based data but that's not at all clear from what you've provided.

Hence, you will probably need to do the following:

- read in the file to an in-memory buffer;
- allocate another (compressed) buffer area, 1% larger with extra 320 bytes;
- call the function to convert normal memory buffer to compressed buffer;
- write the compressed buffer out to another file (amount to write depends on `outsize` returned from function).

---

If you want to be able to handle arbitrary sizes of input files without worrying about the possibility of running out of memory for the buffers, you could "chunk up" the input into (for example) 64,569-byte chunks.

That would require a 64,569-byte input buffer, a 65,535-byte output buffer (64,569 * 1.01 + 320, rounded up), and a way of storing these chunks so you can get at them individually for decompression.

For example, you may need to write a unsigned 16-bit `outsize` (you see now why I chose the input size of 64,569 so as to limit `outsize` to a 16-bit value) followed by that many bytes of data, for every single chunk you do.

The compression will likely be a little less since you're restarting the Huffman tree periodically but it should still be *reasonably* close to what you would have gotten if doing the entire file at once.

Comment: Thank you. I can't receive the uncompressed file that is equal to original one. Something wrong with output buffer as I understand but i have no idea how to calculate it, i tried to calculate size of char* but this function returns size of char* that depends with buffer, it is close circle.